# Difference between "acaso" and "quizá"

Tags: definiciones

I understand that both *Quizá* and *Acaso* are translated to "Perhaps" or "Maybe" in English.  Is there any difference between these two words in Spanish, other than *quizá* being apparently more common? Or are they completely interchangable?

Comment: Just thinking on it, I didn't found an example where they are not interchangeable. RAE's definition of "acaso" includes "quizá" as a synonym. BTW, "acaso" at least in my area is a really strange word.

Comment: @machlas: Which is your area?

Answer (score 4):

ACASO can mean "in the event that" as in "por si acaso", indicating eventuality.

> ¿Acaso no lloran las flores?
>   <sub>Is it not true (or is it not the case) that...?</sub>

In both cases it is used in a subjunctive phrase, indicating possibility.

QUIZÁ indicates "doubt," "possibility," or "potentiality" As in "quizá llueva mañana", equivalent to "tal vez".

It is also used as "maybe".

Comment: Etymologically speaking `acaso` is related with `caso` and `casualidad`, and can be translated with `by chance`. Also etymologically speaking `quizá` means `quien sabe` and can be translated with `who knows`. As an example _quizá lo necesites_ may be translated with _who knows, maybe you'll need it_  while _por si acaso lo necesitas_ may be translated with _just in case you'll need it__.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot explain clearly the difference, but what I can state is that they are not completely interchangable. And there are many examples:

> Quizá llueva mañana

vs

> Acaso llueva mañana

> Quizá lo necesite

vs

> Acaso lo necesite

> -¿Vendrás a la fiesta?
>   -Quizás

vs

> -¿Vendrás a la fiesta?
>   -Acaso

In fact, all the previous sentences using 'acaso' sound completely wrong for me...

My suggestion is to translate both 'maybe' and 'perhaps' as: 'quizá', 'quizás' or even 'a lo mejor'.

I use 'acaso' very few times, only in sentences like:

> ¿Acaso tengo yo la culpa?
>
> Llevaré un abrigo por si acaso hace frío

Comment: Also "Por si acaso" (just in case) is a common usage

Comment: While _acaso_ in your first set of examples is uncommon in normal, urban Spanish from Spain, it is normal in some areas. The only snag would be the last one which would be "Acaso vaya (a la fiesta)". I would say they are indeed interchangeable but I'd recommend to prefer _quizá_ except in constructions like those you mention.

Comment: Yes, "por si acaso" is very common, and @deStrangis, could you provide an example of any area where e.g. "acaso lo necesite" is more normal than "quizás lo necesite" or "a lo mejor lo necesito"? I think it is much less common in all urban, rural and any areas (of Spain, I don't know in Latin America...)

Comment: Not _more_ normal, but perhaps it's just as normal in some areas in Guadalajara, Soria and Aragón in Spain. I've heard it from not too cultured people and it shocked me because I find it perhaps a bit too _literary_

Comment: That's interesting @deStrangis, I'm from Galicia (with lots of rural areas), and I've never heard expressions like that... A mí también me suena como a novela antigua o algo así ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm Mexican and eventhough there are no differences for the use of both (quizá y acaso), "quizá" is more likely to be used in a regular conversation than "acaso". I would only use "acaso" in  "por si acaso" but then it loses the regular translation  "perhaps" or "maybe" for "just in case".

Answer (score 2):

For me 'acaso' is more paired with 'de casualidad', 'será', among others.

'Acaso' is a word which means some kind of doubt but that I'd only use on interrogative questions like these:

> ¿Acaso quiere que también lave la ropa?
>
> ¿Acaso ese hombre se atreverá a robarme?

and perhaps using certain tone of alarm and concern.

On the other hand, 'quizás' is a word as well used to mean some kind of doubt but more flexible, you can use it on affirmative and  negative sentences:

> Quizás mañana vayamos al cine.
>
> Quizás la suegra no venga mañana, ¡qué bueno!

Answer (score 2):

Quizá means "maybe" in the sense of uncertainty or doubt. One doesn't know whether something (good or bad) will happen.

"Acaso" has the connotation of "in case of," and means "maybe" in the sense of "risk;" that is, there is a risk or chance that a (bad) thing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Acaso is for defending yourself from something, because someone is blaming on you for something that you didn't do... for example:

```
-"Debes pagar la ventana" 
- "¿Acaso yo la rompí?"

- "You must pay the window"
- "But I didn't break it" or "did I break it?"
```

And quizá is when you can't make a decision in a situation in which you don't know for sure what will happen or if you're guessing what could possibly happen.. for example..

(First meaning)

```
- ¿Irás a la fiesta?
- Quizá vaya.

- Will you got to the party?
- Maybe I'll go.
```

(Second meaning)

```
- ¿Y que te dirá?
- Quizá que quiere romper conmigo.

- ¿And what will she say?
- Maybe she wants to break up with me.
```

You can also use acaso when you're going to do something but then you think of something (that you are not prepared for) will happen, for example:

```
   - Si acaso ella te dice algo acerca de la ventana, dile que mañana le llevas el dinero.
    - Maybe she says something about the window, tell her you'll pay her back tomorrow.
```

and also when you are forecasting something and you take action against that ...

> - Toma esta sombrilla por si acaso llueve.
> - Take this umbrella in case it rains.

I'm a native spanish speaker.

Comment: ¿alguien se apunta a quitar bloque código y poner bloque texto?

Answer (score 1):

My answer will be localized to Mexico.  (I don't know if it extends to other areas or not.)

*Quizás* or *quizá* mean *maybe* / *perhaps*.

*Acaso* doesn't have a single word equivalent in English.  Here are the two common ways of using it:

1. Llévate un paraguas por si acaso.

   This means: *Take an umbrella just in case*.
2. ¡¿Acaso pasó el camión de basura sin tomar lo nuestro OTRA VEZ?!

   Here is a loose equivalent: *Did the trash truck really skip our house AGAIN?!*

I just checked the [entry in Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/spanish-english/acaso).  It's a bit more comprehensive than this but definitely in line with my examples, so I'll refer you to it for a more complete treatment.

Answer (score 0):

**Quizá** means "Denote the possibilty that happen" and **Acaso** "unforeseen occurrence".